# Cylindrically symmetric vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-derivative

I want to prove that if $u$ is a cylindrically symmetric vector field in $\mathbb R^3$, then $$\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial y}$$

I've tried this by direct derivation, but I think I'm messing up with the unit vectors. by cylindrically symmetric I mean that $u$ is a function of $(r,z)$ only, and that it can be rotated around the z-axis

Comment: Why do you think this should be true?

Comment: @Spencer I convinced myself bysome drawings of basic vector fields, and  actually this statement is necessary to prove something else I know is true for sure. Plus, in Zangwill's book of modern electrodynamics they use this, and I tried to find a proof but couldn´t

Comment: Where in Zangwill? Can you give me a chapter or section number?

Comment: It is actually on jackson's book, and you need to use it to solve an excersice on chapter 4

Comment: I'm looking at the exercises for ch 4 and I don't see this identity in there.

Comment: I see question 4.6 has the notion that there is a charged quadruple in a cylindrically symmetric vector field, I suppose that they have to obtain the electric field as a function of cylindrical coordinates to perform the work required...but yeah no notion of such an identity

Comment: You are both right, they do not give it in Jackson's book, they just gave it in some help to solve the exercise of Jackson's. I thought it was also explicited in Jackson's. Maybe it is not true at all...

Comment: I should have checked Jackson's book myself, I'm so sorry! Still, it is essential for the excercise, so I was still hoping to find a proof

Comment: Forget it, it is not true and you are all right. There is something wrong with the entire way of solving that exercise. @Spencer Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** What was here previously was wrong.

Suppose we have a cylindrically symmetric vector field $\mathbf u$, symmetric about the $z$ axis.

Then we can write, with respect to cylindrical polar basis vectors,
$$\mathbf u = f(r,z)\mathbf e_r + g(r,z)\mathbf e_z.$$
Now, we have $\frac{\partial \mathbf e_z}{\partial x} = 0$ and the same for $y$. The components of $\mathbf u$ in the $x$ and $y$ directions are:
$$\mathbf u_x = f(r,z)\cos\phi,\qquad\qquad\mathbf u_y = f(r,z)\sin\phi,$$
where $\phi$ is the polar angle.

As $x=r\cos\phi$, $1 = \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\cos\phi - r\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}\sin\phi.$
Also, $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ so $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} = \frac{x}{r}$

Therefore,
\begin{align}\frac{\partial \mathbf u_x}{\partial x} &= \frac xrf'(r,z)\cos\phi + \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}f(r,z)\sin\phi\\
&=\frac{x^2}{r^2}f'(r,z) - \left(\frac1{r}-\frac x{r^2}\cos\phi\right)f(r,z)\\
&=\frac{x^2}{r^2}f'(r,z) - \frac{r-x\cos\phi}{r^2}f(r,z)\\
&=\frac1{r^2}\left(x^2f'(r,z) - \frac{y^2}{r}f(r,z)\right)
\end{align}
This is not the same as $\frac{\partial \mathbf u_y}{\partial y}$

Comment: But isn't that an scalar field? I meant vector field, and I'm so sorry, I missed something in the post, I'll correct it right now

Comment: Yes it is, i'll fix it in a minute

Comment: But now it is not cylindrically simmetric... You expressed it in a cartesian basis, which has an implicit dependence on $\theta$

Comment: (I'm so sorry for my english! It is a bit rusty)

Comment: @LunaSage, this is consistent with the definition of cylindrical symmetry you provided. Are you sure that is the one you should be using?

Comment: Have you seen my edit? The derivatives are of the components, it is not a vector derivative

Comment: @LunaSage Either way, I think the problem is more to do with your lack of definition of what you mean by cylindrically symmetric

Comment: That's probably it... In the convention i'm using, it means that the vector field is invariant when rotated on an axis

Comment: Isn't axial symmetry the same as cylindrical symmetry? I think I just confused myself

Comment: Still, you are absolutely right. I'm sorry! I was really confused!